# Dúvida com foreach com group by asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma consulta com agrupamento.

```html
 public List<TB_POSSIBILIDADE> ListarTodos(int id)
        {
            var strQuery = "";
            strQuery += " select ";
            strQuery += " a.IDPOSSIBILIDADE,";
            strQuery += " a.IDTITULOPOSS,";
            strQuery += " A.IDMODALIDADE,";
            strQuery += " a.TITULO,";
            strQuery += " a.DESCRICAO01,";
            strQuery += "  a.DESCRICAO02,";
            strQuery += "  a.DESCRICAO03,";
            strQuery += "  a.VALOR01,";
            strQuery += "  a.VALOR02,";
            strQuery += "  a.VALOR03,";
            strQuery += "  a.MARCA1,";
            strQuery += "  a.MARCA2,";
            strQuery += "  a.MARCA3,";
            strQuery += "  a.VALORAPOSTA1,";
            strQuery += "  a.VALORAPOSTA2,";
            strQuery += "  a.VALORAPOSTA3,";
            strQuery += "  a.VALORTOTAL1,";
            strQuery += "  a.VALORTOTALRETORNO";
            strQuery += " from TB_POSSIBILIDADE a";
            strQuery += " inner join TB_TITULO_POSSIBILIDADE b on a.IDTITULOPOSS = b.IDTITULOPOSS";
            strQuery += string.Format(" where A.IDMODALIDADE = {0}  ", id);
            strQuery += "  group by a.IDTITULOPOSS,a.IDPOSSIBILIDADE,";
            strQuery += "  b.DESCRICAO, a.TITULO,";
            strQuery += "   a.DESCRICAO01, a.DESCRICAO02,";
            strQuery += "   a.DESCRICAO03,a.VALOR01,";
            strQuery += "   a.VALOR02,a.VALOR03,";
            strQuery += "   a.MARCA1,a.MARCA2,";
            strQuery += "   a.MARCA3, a.VALORAPOSTA1,";
            strQuery += "  a.VALORAPOSTA2, a.VALORAPOSTA3,";
            strQuery += "  a.VALORTOTAL1,a.VALORTOTALRETORNO,A.IDMODALIDADE";

            using (contexto = new Contexto())
            {
                var retornoDataReader = contexto.ExecutaComandoComRetorno(strQuery);
                return TransformaReaderEmListaObjetos(retornoDataReader);
            }

        }
```

Tenho um accordion onde no corpo em alguns momentos vou ter mais de 1 opção.

Tenho a primeira opção com apenas uma linha:
Inicial A
titulo : vencedor

Tenho a segunda opção onde tenho 1 titulo e mais 4 conteúdos 
inicial A
titulo : modalidade 02

quero repetir este conteúdo dentro do mesmo accordion

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

fiz a criação de uma classe:

```html
namespace Generico.Dominio
{
   public class TitulosNaLista
    {
        public string Titulo { get; set; }

    }
}
```

No Controller fiz:

```html
//verifcar os titulos na lista
List<TitulosNaLista> ver = new List<TitulosNaLista>();

public bool VerificarTitulos(string Titulo)
{
    return ver.Any(ls => ls.Titulo == Titulo);
}
```

na view:

```html
  <div class="list-group">
                          <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
                              Selecione uma opção:
                          </a>

                          @if (Model.Count() > 0)
                          {

                          foreach (var item in Model)
                          {


                          if(!VerificarTitulos(item.TITULO))
                          {

                          <!--inicio-->
                          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

                              <div class="panel panel-default">
                                  <div class="panel-heading">
                                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                                          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#@Html.DisplayFor(c => item.IDPOSSIBILIDADE)">
                                              @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.TITULO)
                                          </a>
                                      </h4>
                                  </div>


                                  <!--inicio do corpo-->
                                  <div id="@Html.DisplayFor(c => item.IDPOSSIBILIDADE)" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                      <div class="panel-body">


                                          <div class="row">


                                              <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                                                  @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.DESCRICAO01) | R$ @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.VALOR01)
                                                  @Html.TextBoxFor(c => item.VALORAPOSTA1, new { placeholder = "valor ", @class = "form-control" })
                                              </div>


                                              <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                                                  @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.DESCRICAO02) | R$ @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.VALOR02)
                                                  @Html.TextBoxFor(c => item.VALORAPOSTA2, new { placeholder = "valor ", @class = "form-control" })
                                              </div>


                                              <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                                                  @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.DESCRICAO03) | R$ @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.VALOR03)
                                                  @Html.TextBoxFor(c => item.VALORAPOSTA3, new { placeholder = "valor ", @class = "form-control" })
                                              </div>


                                          </div>


                                          <div class="modal-footer">
                                              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="opcao" value="">Gravar</button>
                                          </div>

                                      </div>
                                  </div>

                                  <!--fim do corpo -->


                              </div>
                              }


                          </div>
                          <!--fim -->
                          }

                          }

                          }

                      </div>
```

tenho um erro;
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por que não muda a query adicionando um `group by`?

Comment: Amigo, sugiro que mude a sua pergunta, seu problema está na sua consulta e não no foreach !

Comment: Exponha a consulta que ficará mais fácil de ajudar!

Comment: Como eu falei na minha pergunta, os dados estão na mesma tabela, não tenho duas tabelas

Comment: vou criar uma outra tabela para o titulo e vou postar a dúvida

Comment: @MaurícioJúnior, fiz o ajuste, pode me dar uma ajuda! agradeço

Comment: @MarllonNasser, fiz o ajuste, poderia ver agora! agradeço

Comment: O problema é na query... vc precisa de todas as informações do select? Porque aparentemente você não precisa... Você pode até resolver na view, mas vai ser uma gambiarra no final.

Comment: @MarllonNasser,    Eu alterei a minha pergunta, adicionei o código que foi sugerido pelo  Joy, observe que eu tenho uma classe TitulosNaLista e no controle eu tenho um VerificarTitulos, eu queria ver qual a melhor solução para resolver isso

Comment: Você trás os dados pela query...os dados já vêm de forma errada, né? ... vc tem que tratar na query, não na aplicação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em sua `View` não existe um método `VerificarTitulos()`, por isso o erro.

Para mostrar somente um título (excluindo os demais dados, caso sejam diferentes), você pode fazer de duas formas.

`Group By` direto na consulta ou `Group By` em sua `View` (que eu considero mais simples).

Para fazer o `Group By` na `View`, basta fazer o seguinte:

```
foreach (var item in Model.GroupBy(x => x.Titulo).Select(grp => grp.First()).ToList())
{
  <!--inicio-->
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

      <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#@Html.DisplayFor(c => item.IDPOSSIBILIDADE)">
                      @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.TITULO)
                  </a>
              </h4>
          </div>
          ...
```

Dessa forma você está agrupando por título e selecionando apenas o primeiro valor. Os demais serão desconsiderados.

Vale ressaltar que dependendo da quantidade de registros, a melhor opção seria fazer diretamente na query.

Comment: eu vou tentar, mais o groupy by já existe, veja na consulta sql no inicio da pergunta

Comment: @itasouza Na resposta estou fazendo o group by na aplicação. Para fazer no SQL eu teria que ver melhor o sistema

Comment: ja revolvi o problema, agradeço

Answer (score 3):

Não entendo muito bem a dúvida, mas acho que isto deve ajudar:

```
 <div>
<label>Utilizadores: </label>
<% 
    string [] F = new string[6];
    F[0] = "Paulo Mendes";
    F[1] = "Pedro Litio";
    F[2] = "Maria  ";
    F[3] = "Ana";
    F[4] = "Ricardo";
    F[5] = "Beto";
    for (int a =0; a <= 5; a++)
    {
        Response.Write("<a href=\"#\">  " + F[a] + "</a>");
    }

 %>
  </div>
```

ele vai repetir o link 6 vezes.

Comment: amigo, agradeço a ajuda, mais eu preferi fazer da forma correta, veja se pode me ajudar, agradeço

Comment: o teu problema é que ele repete a mesma informação?

Comment: veja, na imagem, o titulo do accordion se repete, eu quero que quando tiver mais de 1 opção, venha dentro do mesmo accordion

Comment: Esse código que vc mandou não é Razor do ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: O objetivo, é apenas para criar uma ideia de como resolver o problema.

Answer (score 2):

**`Por que ocorre esse erro:`**

O erro ocorre porque o método *"VerificarTitulos"* que você está utilizando na *View* não existe no contexto da *View*.

Como o método *"VerificarTitulos"* foi declarado no seu *Controller* não é possível chamá-lo diretamente como você está fazendo na sua *View* dessa forma:

```
if(!VerificarTitulos(item.TITULO)) // Erro, pois o método não existe na View
{
    ...
}
```

**`Sugestão de uma das possíveis soluções:`**

Uma alternativa seria você criar um propriedade no seu Model que represente um boleano e seja utilizada na condição *if()* na sua *View*.

Exemplo:

Model

```
public class SeuModel
{
    // Propriedades que já estão no seu Model
    public string TITULO { get; set; }
    public int IDPOSSIBILIDADE { get; set; }
    ...

    // Nova propriedade no seu Model
    public bool NovaPropriedadeBoleana { get; set; }

    // Seguindo o código enviado você instancia sua lista
    // Pelo seu código não vi como, mas imagino que você preenche a lista
    // Então você poderia usar o método para ao invés de retornar um bool
    // ele configurar essa NovaPropriedadeBoleana exemplo:

    List<TitulosNaLista> ver = new List<TitulosNaLista>();

    ... // preenche a lista

    // Configura a propriedade NovaPropriedadeBoleana 
    public void VerificarTitulos()
    {
        NovaPropriedadeBoleana = ver.Any(ls => ls.Titulo == Titulo);
    }
}
```

View

```
@model SeuProjeto.Models.SeuModel

    <div class="list-group">
        ...
        @if (Model.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
               if(!item.NovaPropriedadeBooleana) // Ao invés de usar o método você usaria uma propriedade do seu Model
               {
                    ....
               } ...
            } ...
         } ...
    </div>
```

Outra opção é fazer o *Group By* conforme a resposta do Randrade, aí no caso nem precisaria do método que deu erro.

Comment: eu vou tentar, mais o groupy by já existe, veja na consulta sql no inicio da pergunta

Comment: Ah sim, como eu foquei minha resposta de acordo com o erro que você citou na pergunta, só depois eu vi que além do erro, você estava com dúvida no group by também

Comment: ja revolvi o problema, agradeço

Answer (score 1):

```
 //criar uma classe
public class Titulos_ Na_lista
 {
public string Titulo { get; set; }

  }

  // aqui é a tua página

 List<Titulos_ Na_lista> Ver = new List<Titulos_ Na_lista>();

 public bool VERIFICAR_Titulos(int Titulo)
 {
     return Ver.Any(l => l.Titulo ==Titulo);
 }

 foreach (var item in Model)

{
      if (!VERIFICAR_IDs(item.TITULO))
      {
              <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#@Html.DisplayFor(c => item.IDPOSSIBILIDADE)">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.TITULO)
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>

                        <!--inicio do corpo-->
                        <div id="@Html.DisplayFor(c => item.IDPOSSIBILIDADE)" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">


                                <div class="row">


                                    <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.DESCRICAO01) | R$ @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.VALOR01)
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => item.VALORAPOSTA1, new { placeholder = "valor ", @class = "form-control" })
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.DESCRICAO02) | R$ @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.VALOR02)
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => item.VALORAPOSTA2, new { placeholder = "valor ", @class = "form-control" })
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.DESCRICAO03) | R$ @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.VALOR03)
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => item.VALORAPOSTA3, new { placeholder = "valor ", @class = "form-control" })
                                    </div>


                                </div>


                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="opcao" value="">Gravar</button>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!--fim do corpo -->
                    </div>

                </div>
      }
}
```

Comment: Joy, quase deu certo, eu alterei o texto da minha pergunta fazendo os passos que você esta informando, veja o que acontece, agradeço

Comment: ja revolvi o problema, agradeço

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, vc está usando MVC com qual banco de dados? É uma escolha não usar Entity Framework, ou não conheces?

Francamente, vejo várias falhas no seu padrão de desenvolvimento que geram os erros!

**1)** Concatenação de uma mesma string várias vezes!

**Solução:** Usa-se a classe StringBuilder para isso, porém eu não usaria nem a stringbuilder, usaria Linq do Entities - Entity Framework

**2)** Usando SQL chumbado no código e trocando os valores com string.format:

**Solução:** Não se usa desta forma por permitir SQL Injection, se usa classes com **SQLParameter**

**3)** Você está imaginando que um método criado na Controller é acessível na View!

**Solução:** Não é! na View vc pode instanciar uma nova chamada de qualquer classe (colocando using do namespace no início).

**4)** Use Entity Framework, é fácile simples... há muitos exemplos na internet!

**5)** E por fim, seria mais legível para nós, colocares uma imagem com o que tu queres (protótipo) e a sua base de dados!

Comment: Mauricio, o meu projeto tem 4 camadas, aplicação, domínio, repositório e web. No projeto web eu tenho a referencia das dlls, eu estou seguindo um padrão que eu aprendi usando sim o sql puro, eu já usei o Enitity Framework, linq  que no meu ponto de vista não é bom por várias razoes, pode até ser mais fácil, talvez você tenha outro conceito mais esta facilidade do Link para coisas simples até que e bom, mais quando você precisa fazer alguma coisa mais complexa ai você tem um problema porque o linq e uma nova forma de fazer as coisas, e desenvolver para web para tem muita linguagem envolvida.

Comment: Veja @itasouza no início realmente o Entity Framework era meio complicado, hoje em sua versão 6 está muito estável e desonera muitas coisas, permitindo uma otimização considerável no desenvolvimento.

Comment: Desenvolvo utilizando linq a anos, e lhe aconselho a usar, mataríamos este seu problema em segundos!

Só para compreenderes, o linq to entities, otimiza de várias formas uma consulta ao SQL, e para você ter noção de uma das coisas que mais me agrada, ele consegue compor em uma única consulta SQL (nativo) ... uma consulta Master -> Details de várias camadas...

Comment: Já conseguistes resolver a questão ? Se não coloca um protótipo do resultado final que desejas com a estrutura das tabelas, que assim fica fácil de resolvermos!

Comment: eu conseguir resolver usando uma partial view